# Showing a recursive method with UML

Tags: c#, java, uml

Is there a way to show a recursive method with UML class diagram modelling?

[image: class diagram]

In the above class I have a static method Calculate and I want to show that this method alone calls itself recursively and not any other methods or the class. How do I show this in UML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sequence diagrams you can show method calls made by a method, it is therefore possible to show a method is recursive (caling itself). A class diagram, on the contrary, models only the static structure of the system. If you want to emphasize a method is recursive, the only way is to use a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stereotype "recursively" or add a tagged value "recursive=true" to add that information.